# Visual Studio 2008: is there any way to turn on the Class Name/Method Name drop downs in C#? (like VB.Net has)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm working in .Net 3.5sp1 in C# for an ASP.Net solution and I'm wondering if there's any way to turn on the Class Name and Method Name drop-downs in the text editor that VB.Net has at the top. It's one of the few things from VB that I actually miss.

Edit: Also, is there any way to get the drop downs to be populated with the possible events?

e.g. (Page Events) | (Declarations)

Comment: Aren't those the little things with lightning bolt icons?

Comment: Yeah, is there any way to get them to show up? Right now it only displays events that have been defined in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go To:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> General -> Navigation Bar
```

Make sure it is clicked, and that should show something at the top of your code that has all the classes and methods listed in your file.

Comment: hmm, now is there any way to list all the _possible_ events like vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2008 (and probably earlier versions):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#(*) -> General -> Navigation bar

(*) or your preferred editor language

Answer (score 1):

Try

[Tools]->[Options]->[Text Editor]->[C#]->[General]->[Check "Navigation Bar]

Answer (score 0):

note that the lists don't fill in until the cursor is within the namespace/class